# How to make my stylesheet switch, stick

Tags: javascript, html

I have written some code that will change stylesheets between the normal one and accessible version.
In theory this works, however as soon as you refresh the page it goes back to the default version. I know I need to store a cookie of some sort and I've tried a couple of scripts I've found on Google, but none work.
If anyone has an idea of what I need in order for the selected stylesheet to stick throughout the site until the other is requested, that would be appreciated.

Code so far:

```
<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="normal" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/accessible.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="accessible" />

<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('normal');return false;" name="theme" value="" id="normal" title="View the site in it's original format">
    <input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('accessible');return false;" name="theme" value="" id="accessible" title="View the site in it's simplest form">
</form>
```

This is the javascript I've incorporated, which seems to have a bug in it somewhere, but I can't for the life of me find it:

```
var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 30 ;

function switch_style ( css_title )
{
var i, link_tag ;
for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
  link_tag[i].title) {
  link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
  if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
    link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
  }
}
set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
  style_cookie_duration );
}
}
function set_style_from_cookie()
{
var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
if (css_title.length) {
switch_style( css_title );
}
}
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                   ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
document.cookie = cookie_name +
                   "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                   "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                   24 * lifespan_in_days +
                   "; path=/" + domain_string ;
}
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
    var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                    '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                    cookie_name +
                    '=([^;]*)' );
    return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
}
return '' ;
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` you won't need the `;return false;`

Comment: Why are you trying to solve this in JavaScript? It's better solved server-side.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). "I've searched tutorials and nothing work" doesn't count as trying, by the way.

Comment: Yes you can do this by setting a javascript cookie but you can't expect someone to write the code entirely for you. You need to do some research, have a crack at it yourself then post code for people to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code I've tried so far...

Comment: Given the laws surrounding cookies in some countries, I'd avoid them all together. I'd just go with localstorage. Easy, persistent, legal requirement to disclose its use not present. Note - if serving to the UK, you'd likely want to ensure that the accessible one is the default. Otherwise, how are vision impaired people going to select it?

Answer (score 1):

There are some small errors in the get_cookie function.

remove:

```
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
    var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
            '(^|;)[\s]*' +
            cookie_name +
            '=([^;]*)' );
    return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
}
return '' ;
}
```

replace with:

```
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
    var cookie_value = cookie_string.match(
        '(^|;) ?' + 
        cookie_name + 
        '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );
    return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
}
return '' ;
}
```

Hope it helps you or someone else with the same problem.

Comment: btw this code appears on many sites on the web as a 'tutorial' for switching style sheets with javascript. The same problem occurs in all of them, so there will probably be others searching for the same issue. This is not my solution, I eventually found this solution by Michael Joseph and solved the problem for me.